# MvxRecyclerView NotSupportedException

Tags: xamarin.android, mvvmcross

I want to implement list of different types using MvxRecyclerView and ItemTemplateSelector but I get not supported exception when I only try to show activity with MvxRecyclerView.

*System.NotSupportedException has been thrown.
Could not activate JNI Handle 0x7ffc627020 (key_handle 0xc743032) of Java type 'mvvmcross/droid/support/v7/recyclerview/MvxRecyclerView' as managed type 'MvvmCross.Droid.Support.V7.RecyclerView.MvxRecyclerView'.*

The same when I add binding to ItemsSource, MvxTemplateSelector or MvxItemTemplate. Nothing helps. What am I missing?

Comment: I found a solution. MvvmCross.Droid.Support.V7.RecyclerView is deprecated, we should use MvxRecyclerView from MvvmCross.DroidX.RecyclerView.

Answer (score 0):

I decided to post my answer as I had the same issue in `MvvmCross 8.0.2` despite using the `MvvmCross.DroidX.RecyclerView.MvxRecyclerView`.

The solution in my case was to add `MvvmCross.Plugin.FieldBinding` package to the Droid project.